# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'term'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Have "Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'term'" issue while running-

**rake assets:precompile**

Here is the complete error.

```
[chitra@localhost develop]$ rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'term'
  (in /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts/web_console.js:1)
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in `process_require_directive'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@upgrade/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also clear the assets pipeline by -

**rake assets:clear**

But still having the same issue.

Please help me out to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because web console is not designed to be used in production, and hence is not usually precompiled. Try precompiling with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the file `term` in assets.rb before running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution but the issue was different.

Assets folder was in public directory. Now I removed that and problem get resolved.